# sanitation during mash and sparge

Tags: all-grain, sanitation

I've been brewing extract batches for a couple of months, and have never lost a batch to poor sanitation. I lost my first all grain batch of beer, and I think that I am sanitizing my brew kettle and fermenter well. Any advice when sanitizing mad tuns, and any tips for all grain sanitation in general?

Thanks

Comment: you don't really need to explicitly sanitize the boil kettle, since the boil will take care of that. How are you sanitizing the fermentor?

Comment: In what way did the batch fail?  Are you sure it was a sanitation issue?

Comment: I opened the fermenter and it was full of mold (and smelled like death). i usually just soak everything in starsan for 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: How long did you boil for?

Comment: About 65-70 minutes

Comment: Any contamination while cooling? Any chance the yeast you pitched died? (too high wort temperature for example). Something not sanitized touched your wort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mash tun simply needs to be cleaned - no need to sanitize - any microbes are wiped out in the boil.

If you are getting contamination issues specifically with all-grain, then it has to be post-boil - I can only think that it may be because of your chiller, assuming you weren't using that when doing an extract brew.

Comment: I didn't use a wort chiller, although I will try one with the next batch.

Comment: If you didn't use a wort chiller, then you either waited a long time to pitch your yeast, allowing wild yeast to infect the batch, or you pitched when it was too hot and killed off your yeast. The biggest advantage of a wort chiller is to allow you to quickly pitch your yeast before anything else can get a foothold. We cannot brew under sterilized conditions, so there will always be some bacteria or wild yeast present that would love to take over your beer. Pitching a large quantity of active yeast crowds everything else out.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to worry about pre-boil sanitation other than just generally use a clean mash tun etc.. contamination would have to occur post boil of your wort.